# Counting Time within ranges in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

So I did look through a couple of existing answers, but they were all in some programing language (ie, RUBY, PHP, etc).  I also managed to figure out a way to do what I want but some of my formulas felt either hard coded or verbose.  So my question is, is there a cleaner way to write my formulas to achieve my goal.

What I am starting with is a simple line to calculate cost of electricity usage.  It look like:

```
+─────────────+────────+───────+───────+─────────+──────────+───────────+───────────+────────+──────────+───────────+───────────+──────────+──────────────+─────────────+
|             |        |       |       |         | KW used  |           |           |        | Rate     |           |           | Usage    | Delivery     | Total Cost  |
| Date        | Start  | Stop  | KW/H  | Season  | On-Peak  | Mid-Peak  | Off-Peak  | Total  | On-Peak  | Mid-Peak  | Off-Peak  | Cost     | Cost         |             |
+─────────────+────────+───────+───────+─────────+──────────+───────────+───────────+────────+──────────+───────────+───────────+──────────+──────────────+─────────────+
| 2022/12/17  | 05:00  | 22:00 | 1.44  | Winter  | 0        | 0         | 24.48     | 24.48  | 0.17     | 0.113     | 0.082     | 2.00736  | 1.141296768  | 3.15        |
+─────────────+────────+───────+───────+─────────+──────────+───────────+───────────+────────+──────────+───────────+───────────+──────────+──────────────+─────────────+
```

The first 4 columns are user entry fields and correspond to columns B through E.  The remainder of the columns F through P are all formulas.

My seasonal time bands are contained in the following table

```
+─────────+──────────────+─────────────+───────────+──────────+──────────+──────────+
| Season  | Start        | Stop        | Time      | Start    | Stop     | Rate     |
|         |              |             | Period    | (HH:mm)  | (HH:mm)  | ($/Kwh)  |
+─────────+──────────────+─────────────+───────────+──────────+──────────+──────────+
| Summer  | May 01       | October 31  | Off-Peak  | 00:00    | 07:00    | 0.082    |
|         |              |             | Mid-Peak  | 07:00    | 11:00    | 0.113    |
|         |              |             | On-Peak   | 11:00    | 17:00    | 0.17     |
|         |              |             | Mid-Peak  | 17:00    | 19:00    | 0.113    |
|         |              |             | Off-Peak  | 19:00    | 24:00    | 0.082    |
+─────────+──────────────+─────────────+───────────+──────────+──────────+──────────+
| Winter  | November 01  | April 30    | Off-Peak  | 00:00    | 07:00    | 0.082    |
|         |              |             | On-Peak   | 07:00    | 11:00    | 0.17     |
|         |              |             | Mid-Peak  | 11:00    | 17:00    | 0.113    |
|         |              |             | On-Peak   | 17:00    | 19:00    | 0.17     |
|         |              |             | Off-Peak  | 19:00    | 24:00    | 0.082    |
+─────────+──────────────+─────────────+───────────+──────────+──────────+──────────+

Note: weekends and holidays are Off-Peak
```

To aid with formula reading (or so I thought) I used the following named ranges:

```
Season_1 =$B$75 ("Summer")
Season_1_Start =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),5,1) ("May 01")
Season_1_End =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),10,31) ("Oct 31")
Season_1_TimeRates =$E$75:$H$79 ("Off-Peak" to 0.82)
Season_2 =$B$80 ("Winter")
Season_2_Start =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),11,1) ("Nov 01")
Season_2_End =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),4,30) ("Apr 30")
Season_2_TimeRates =$E$80:$H$84 ("Off-Peak" to 0.82)
TimeRates =IF($F3="Summer",Season_1_TimeRates,Season_2_TimeRates)
```

Step 1

Determining the season in F4

I used the following formula in F4.

```
=IF(AND($B3>=DATE(YEAR($B3),MONTH(Season_1_Start),DAY(Season_1_Start)),$B3<=DATE(YEAR($B3),MONTH(Season_1_End),DAY(Season_1_End))),Season_1,Season_2)
```

It seamed reasonable and substituted the year of the actual entry for making date comparison.  I took the approach of if its not within the range for summer, then by default it has to be winter.  Part of me is thinking I should check the winter date check.  If both date checks fail then toss up a check date statement or the like.

Step 2

Determine how many hours are in each category according to the table and place results in G through I.  This is where things go a little ugly for me.  After chasing my tail in circle for a little bit I said screw it and plunged in with some hard coding and got something that worked but looked rather ugly and lengthy to me

I started out by figuring out that each time range check had 6 possible outcomes.  I boiled those outcomes down to 2 possible results:  0 or Formula.

```
SB = Start Before
SI = Start Inside
SA = Start After
FB = Finish Before
FI = Finish Inside
FA = Finish After
```

[image]

So the results were either 0 because the time range in C and D are outside of the Time range of the table.  Or its some form of Finish - Start.

I couldn't figure out how to make it count the hours in the range using the title (ie On-Peak) because there were sometimes more than one entry depending on the season in F.  So what I did as a working step was to create a formula that would count the hours for each of the 5 time ranges instead of the names of the time range:

[image]

To get the hours I used the following formulas for each row:

```
=IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,1,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,1,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,1,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,1,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,1,2),INDEX(TimeRates,1,2),$C3))*24
=IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,2,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,2,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,2,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,2,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,2,2),INDEX(TimeRates,2,2),$C3))*24
=IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,3,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,3,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,3,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,3,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,3,2),INDEX(TimeRates,3,2),$C3))*24
=IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,4,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,4,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,4,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,4,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,4,2),INDEX(TimeRates,4,2),$C3))*24
=IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,5,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,5,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,5,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,5,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,5,2),INDEX(TimeRates,5,2),$C3))*24
```

I wound up hard coding the entries because ultimately these are going to wind up in the formula for G3 through I3.  Otherwise I could have used the Range # column as index points.

So the next problem I had was adding ranges with the same name together.  Could have used SUMIF if I was keeping the table, but in my head I could not as A) I was not keeping the table, B) This would eventually need to be in a row that could be copied down.

So I looked at what needed to be done for each season and it was not bad...IF the formula was short.

[image]

So basically need an IF statement looking for summer and follow the addition of appropriate seasonal ranges for each range type.  Seems simple enough but it gave me the following formulas for G3 through I3:

```
=$E3*IF(OR(WEEKDAY($B3)={1,7}),0,IF($F3="Summer",IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,3,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,3,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,3,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,3,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,3,2),INDEX(TimeRates,3,2),$C3)),IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,2,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,2,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,2,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,2,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,2,2),INDEX(TimeRates,2,2),$C3))+IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,4,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,4,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,4,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,4,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,4,2),INDEX(TimeRates,4,2),$C3))))*24
=$E3*IF(OR(WEEKDAY($B3)={1,7}),0,IF($F3="Summer",IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,2,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,2,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,2,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,2,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,2,2),INDEX(TimeRates,2,2),$C3))+IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,4,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,4,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,4,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,4,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,4,2),INDEX(TimeRates,4,2),$C3)),IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,3,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,3,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,3,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,3,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,3,2),INDEX(TimeRates,3,2),$C3))))*24
=$E3*IF(OR(WEEKDAY($B3)={1,7}),$D3-$C3,IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,1,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,1,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,1,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,1,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,1,2),INDEX(TimeRates,1,2),$C3))+IF(OR($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,5,2),$C3>=INDEX(TimeRates,5,3)),0,IF($D3<=INDEX(TimeRates,5,3),$D3,INDEX(TimeRates,5,3))-IF($C3<=INDEX(TimeRates,5,2),INDEX(TimeRates,5,2),$C3)))*24
```

**So the question is, is there way to use formulas that would allow for the tidying up of what is currently in place for cells G3 to I3 (last 3 formulas in this question) that can be copied downward?**

**UPDATE** as requested

I am working on the table on the top, below it is my building block area for thoughts.  You may recognize some of the shots above from it.

[image]

[image]

Using Excel 2013

Comment: This is a lot of detail - thanks for taking the time. But it's difficult to tell what's going on because there aren't enough screenshots showing the column and row headers. You refer to F4 or E3 but don't show what that is. If you could add a single screenshot showing the data, I think we can probably help. Also, can you confirm your Excel version?

Comment: @FlexYourData updated as requested.  I am using Excel 2013, hence the tag.

Comment: Thanks and I only ask because sometimes people spam the excel tags. No offense intended.

Comment: could you may be provide an excel file. otherwise it is difficult to imagine.